# Increase and decrease jQuery slider ui value by one step

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I've created a slider that displays value based on specified array. I want to increase or decrease the value by one step using 'plus/minus' buttons which seems working however the value is not updating.

https://jsfiddle.net/martynava/jrx8rz79/6/

[slider with input field and increase/decrease buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZGoa.png)

Code below:

```js
$(function() {
var sizes = [ "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "1000" ];
$("#slider-range-max").slider({
  range: "max",
  min: 0,
  max: sizes.length - 1,
  step: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#cap").val(sizes[ui.value]);
  }
});
$( "#cap" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) + ' TB' );
});


$("#plus1").click(function() {
    var value = $("#slider-range-max").slider("value")
        , step = $("#slider-range-max").slider("option", "step");

    $("#slider-range-max").slider("value", value + step);
});

$("#minus1").click(function () {
    var value = $("#slider-range-max").slider("value")
        , step = $("#slider-range-max").slider("option", "step");

    $("#slider-range-max").slider("value", value - step);        
});
```

Does anyone know what is the best way to make it work. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code like for instance the click events must be inside the document ready otherwise you need to use the document on event listener. What you are looking for is:

```js
$(function () {
  var sizes = ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "1000"];
  $("#slider-range-max").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 0,
    max: sizes.length - 1,
    step: 1,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $("#cap").val(sizes[0] + ' TB');
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
      $("#cap").val(sizes[ui.value] + ' TB');
    }
  });

  $("#plus1").click(function () {
    var value = $("#slider-range-max").slider("value");
    var step = $("#slider-range-max").slider("option", "step");

    $("#slider-range-max").slider("value", value + step);
  });

  $("#minus1").click(function () {
    var value = $("#slider-range-max").slider("value")
    var step = $("#slider-range-max").slider("option", "step");

    $("#slider-range-max").slider("value", value - step);
  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 90%;
  background: #2A3137;
  /* -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #999;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #999;*/
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.slider .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  background: #10A447;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -16px;
  left: 50px;
  border-style: none;
  box-shadow: none;

}

input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid #10A447;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 120px;
  color: #2A3137;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.minus, .plus {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="quote-input" class="slider-input">
    <div id="minus1" class="minus"><span>-</span></div>
    <div id="plus1" class="plus">+</div>
    <input type="text" id="cap" class="slider-value">


    <div id="slider-range-max" class="slider">
        <span class="ui-slider-handle"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the change event in the slider eliminates the need for the change on click 
`code`    $("#cap").val(sizes[value - step] + ' TB');